# View Asynchronous JavaScript calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebug

I've upgraded the tracking script for Google Analytics to the Asynchronous version. The only issue I have is being able to debug the calls. I was able to track the older version in Firebug using the approach outlined on [this site](http://pranshuarya.com/jaal/Development/how-to-check-google-analytics-event-tracking.html), but now cannot view the gaq.push calls. Is there way to view this in Firebug or another tool?

This is my sample test page I'm trying to track:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Google Analytics Event Tracking</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-13250000-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script');
            ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to confirm that "_gaq.push" is actually working.

Comment: I figured it out. I was testing from my local PC and the URL was http://pcname, once I deployed the test page above to our test server that has a FQDN, then the GET requests associated with the push commands were displayed in Firebug. Something built-in to ga.js must suppress the push event if using non-FQDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TamperData plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/966) for Firefox is very handy. It lets you see all HTTP traffic, with filtering etc.  It also has a facility that lets you modify headers before the browser starts the HTTP transaction, which seems pretty awesome but I've never used it.

Comment: Just installed, but it is not showing the Asynchronous calls, just the calls to get the ga.js file. Is there an option I need to turn on to view the Asynchronous calls?

Comment: It shows **all** HTTP traffic out of the browser.  Are you sure that the HTTP calls are being made?  I've been using that plugin for many years now and I've never seen it "miss" HTTP traffic.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to figure out. Unfortunately I cannot view the traffic in GA because it takes up to a day to report the event data so I'm trying to figure out if it is at least being sent. I'll post my sample page above so you can see what I'm testing.

Comment: Although I figured out the issue, your suggestion was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue, and so I did a google search and ended up on this stack overflow question.. I too thought that this would just show up as a xhr request in firebug as that would be the simple way to track an event. Turns out they are using a 1x1 pixel gif to do the tracking! If you look in the Net > All tab in Firebug you will see a GET request made looking similar to this:

```
https://ssl.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.2.4&utms=28&utmn=1818843630&utmhn=dev-marketplace.asos.com&utmt=event&utme=5(my-home*sub-nav-click*blog-posts)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1080&utmvp=1920x618&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-gb&utmje=0&utmfl=11.1%20r102&utmdt=Build%20%23%20Developer%20Live%20Feed%20ASOS%20Marketplace&utmhid=1950484512&utmr=-&utmp=%2Flivefeed%2Fblogposts&utmac=UA-23521416-1&utmcc=__utma%3D159014575.706813547.1328542287.1328542287.1328604985.2%3B%2B__utmz%3D159014575.1328542287.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=6AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ~
```

These are the params sent in the request

```
utmac   UA-23521416-1
utmcc   __utma=159014575.706813547.1328542287.1328542287.1328604985.2;+__utmz=159014575.1328542287.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
utmcs   UTF-8
utmdt   Build # Developer Live Feed ASOS Marketplace
utme    5(my-home*sub-nav-click*blog-posts)
utmfl   11.1 r102
utmhid  1950484512
utmhn   dev-marketplace.asos.com
utmje   0
utmn    1818843630
utmp    /livefeed/blogposts
utmr    -
utms    28
utmsc   24-bit
utmsr   1920x1080
utmt    event
utmu    6AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ~
utmul   en-gb
utmvp   1920x618
utmwv   5.2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this by looking at the Resources tab in Chrome Developer Tools:

http://drktd.com/45VJ (notice the yellow 'XHR' -- that means XMLHttpRequest, which is the kind of call you're likely looking for)

If you need an in-depth view of each request into/out of your system, you should really install [Charles Proxy.](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)  It is the best of breed for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see the requests happening in FireBug, then they are not happening. Google Analytics is not somehow sidestepping the browser's ability to track what HTTP requests it is making, your code is simply not making them.